# Get Non-Blank Entries Excel

Tags: excel

I have a table with values with blank rows. I'm trying to copy over all the non-blank entries into another table via a formula (kind like what `=UNIQUE()` does with unique values).
Basically, the left table is the data, and I want to automatically have it copy the non-blank values in the table and organize it into something like the right table.

[image]

I did a lot of googling, but I can't find a formula to do this. Does anyone have a method to achieve this without using VBA?

EDIT: I can't filter the blank rows b/c other cells have information that people need to see

Comment: Filter out the blank rows, copy, then paste in a new worksheet?

Comment: Why no VBA? Would be very easy with it

Comment: Have you not tried the simple `=FILTER(A1:C8,A1:A8<>"")`?